# C# - WMI InvalidOperationException when trying to run a script on a remote machine

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, wmi, remote-process

I'm trying to execute a script on a remote machine in the same domain, with the same user account logged on to both the machines. Note the script is also stored on yet another machine.

**Code**

```
string prop = propertyName
object[] cmd = { String.Format("cscript \\\\machine\\script.wsf", envId, application) };
ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("\\\\" + prop + "\\root\\cimv2\\Win32_Process");

mc.InvokeMethod("Create", cmd);
```

**Exception**

```
[InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.]
   System.Management.ManagementObject.InvokeMethod(String methodName, Object[] args) +388806
```

**Conclusion**

I'm new to using WMI, so I'm not sure if what I'm doing wrong is obvious, though looking around this exception type is used in many situations, and am having trouble finding out what the actual issue is, so help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it work when executing it locally? If not, you are shit out of luck. Many things in WMI is just not implemented... Remoting or WCF might be a better option.

Comment: You mean does the script work when run locally, or does it work when i set the target machine as myself?  I guess what I mean is, are you asking me if the WMI code works or the script works?

Comment: I never use the "ultra-cool-short" syntax, because you'll probably not have the right level of control over the process properties. I know, that remote process will work [although my experience stems from w2k3 only]. As "leppie" already mentioned, it will usually NOT work, if you attempt to excute network resources [location of your script to excute], because this would require another authentication step to your "\\\\machine\\...". The minimum requirement for this stept would be to use kerberos auth! I never did that. What is your authentication and network landscape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the windows service hosting the process was not running under an account that had permission to execute on the target machine.

My mistake!

Answer (score 3):

Your "\root\cimv2\Win32_Process" should be "\root\cimv2:Win32_Process"

Note the colon, this is what I use.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

`result.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", ownerArgs)`

The problem was that I was trying to execute that on an object I retrieved with the following WMI query.

`SELECT ProcessId, ExecutablePath, CommandLine FROM Win32_Process`

Changing it to `SELECT * FROM Win32_Process` fixed it.

I could've probably, also, specifically requested Username and Domain.

Comment: You need to select the Handle as well, e.g `SELECT Handle, ProcessId FROM Win32_Process`